Error when running a nest.js docker image that persists in the oracle database
I have a Nest.js application that runs in the docker container and connects to an oracle database.
The Dockerfile is:
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache libaio unzip

COPY instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip /tmp/

RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip -d /usr/lib/oracle && \
    rm /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so.21.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so

WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY . .

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start:prod"]

The database configuration class is:
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';
import { Env } from 'src/env';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService implements OnModuleDestroy {
  private connection: oracledb.Connection;

  constructor() {
    this.initializeOracleClient();
  }

  private getClientOptions() {
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
      return { libDir: 'C:\\oracle\\instantclient_19_22' };
    } else if (process.platform === 'darwin' && process.arch === 'x64') {
      return { libDir: `${process.env.HOME}/Downloads/instantclient_19_8` };
    } else if (process.platform === 'linux') {
      return { libDir: '/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8' };
    }
    return undefined;
  }
  

  private initializeOracleClient() {
    const clientOpts = this.getClientOptions();
    if (clientOpts) oracledb.initOracleClient(clientOpts);
  }

  private async openConnection() {
    try {
      this.connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: Env.OWNER,
        password: Env.PWD,
        connectString: Env.CONNECT_STRING,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Falha na conexão com o banco de dados Oracle');
    }
  }

  async executeQuery(query: string, params: any[] = []): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.connection) await this.openConnection();
    try {
      const result = await this.connection.execute(query, params, {
        outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,
        autoCommit: true,
      });
      return result.rows;
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error(`Erro ao executar a consulta: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    if (this.connection) {
      try {
        await this.connection.close();
      } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(`Erro ao fechar a conexão: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
  }
  
}

In the Root of project exists the file instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip
When building the image, I get:
 *  Executing task: docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t mvallergyagentsearch:latest "." 

[+] Building 6.3s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                          docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 540B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20-alpine                                                                           1.3s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 113B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:c13b26e7e602ef2f1074aef304ce6e9b7dd284c419b35d89fcf3cc8e44a8def9                     0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:c13b26e7e602ef2f1074aef304ce6e9b7dd284c419b35d89fcf3cc8e44a8def9                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 18.57kB                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libaio unzip                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] COPY instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip /tmp/                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip -d /usr/lib/oracle &&     rm /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.zip &&    0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] WORKDIR /usr/src/api                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] COPY . .                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] RUN yarn install                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [8/8] RUN yarn build                                                                                                             0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                      4.9s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:ca40a453fb589078768de8d2861fad58c8a53a93d3b88b011b9b967a8b81fee7                                           0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:8fe58274b8766e67173a018af65077ff4c7be8ead7395cc6ff6ed7d07297a203                                             0.0s
 => => exporting attestation manifest sha256:15f8deb4b3ec5eebf5c5017cdb54fae9e59bd92811742434ed57bb6438293585                               0.0s
 => => exporting manifest list sha256:a59de9a6a7a5a65aab0108a53399dc620302a1aa9cdc764aef7d3fce7497e5ab                                      0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/mvallergyagentsearch:latest                                                                              0.0s
 => => unpacking to docker.io/library/mvallergyagentsearch:latest                                                                           4.8s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/rcvydlmwn1crtosbq8d4m1oyo

What's next:
    View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

When rotating the image, I get:
2024-11-08 13:29:21 yarn run v1.22.22
2024-11-08 13:29:21 $ node dist/main
2024-11-08 13:29:21 [Nest] 27  - 11/08/2024, 4:29:21 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
2024-11-08 13:29:21 [Nest] 27  - 11/08/2024, 4:29:21 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so: No such file or directory". See https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
2024-11-08 13:29:21 Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
2024-11-08 13:29:21 You must have Linux arm64 Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
2024-11-08 13:29:21 If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
2024-11-08 13:29:21 https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html
2024-11-08 13:29:21 
2024-11-08 13:29:21 Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so: No such file or directory". See https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
2024-11-08 13:29:21 Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
2024-11-08 13:29:21 You must have Linux arm64 Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
2024-11-08 13:29:21 If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
2024-11-08 13:29:21 https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html
2024-11-08 13:29:21 
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at Object.initOracleClient (/usr/src/api/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:710:20)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at DatabaseService.initializeOracleClient (/usr/src/api/dist/service/database.service.js:35:22)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at new DatabaseService (/usr/src/api/dist/service/database.service.js:18:14)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at Injector.instantiateClass (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:365:19)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at callback (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:45)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:144:24)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at async Injector.loadInstance (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at async Injector.loadProvider (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at async /usr/src/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
2024-11-08 13:29:21     at async Promise.all (index 6)
2024-11-08 13:29:21 error Command failed with exit code 1.
2024-11-08 13:29:21 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

How to solve this problem?

btw this has nothing to do with nestjs. It seems to be a issue related with nodejs and that oracle db lib

Read the node-oracledb docs about why passing libDir to initOracleClient on Linux doesn't do what you think it does, and shouldn't be passed.  On Linux you must set the system library search path before running Node.js. But do you need to use Thick mode at all?  Can you use the default Thin mode that doesn't need Instant Client? If you do need Instant Client then don't use Alpine.  You don't gain much space but gain pain and instability. Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python

The error message is:

Error loading shared library /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so: No such file or directory

Your RUN is doing:
    ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so.21.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so

You should be linking that into the same directory:
    ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so.21.1 /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so

